# how check div is empty after all span removed without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need to check the div is empty after remove all span inside that div,without refreshing page.

this my code

html

```
<div id="word_splatter" class="numbersfont">
    <span class="listed">N</span>
    <span class="listed">y</span>
    <span class="listed">k</span>
    <span class="listed">r</span>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.listed').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
    });
}); 

if ($('#word_splatter').is(':empty')) { 
    {
        alert('The container contains something.');
    } 
    else {
       alert('The container is empty.');
    }
```

Comment: Nest your checking code within the delete code.

Comment: put the `is(':empty')` check inside the click handler, although I don't see the point of checking it after emptying it, as it's guaranteed to be empty. Also the syntax of your `if` statement is incorrect.

Comment: `if( $('#word_splatter').is(':empty') ) 
               alert('The container contains something.');` ???  If it is empty, it ***doesn't*** contain something

Comment: Questions where the problem is a logical one and not a coding one shouldn't be allowed here.

Comment: in if part you should be checking negation of your actual statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the condition after `remove()` is called, also `:empty` may not be good choice because it will return false if there is a textnode in the calling parent

```
$(function () {
    $('.ui-draggable').click(function () {
        $(this).remove();

        if ($('#word_splatter *').length) {
            alert('The container contains something.');
        } else {
            alert('The container is empty.');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.listed').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();

        if(! $('#word_splatter').is(':empty') ) { 
        alert('The container contains something.');
        } else {
        alert('The container is empty.');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="word_splatter" class="numbersfont">
                        <span class="listed">N</span>
                        <span class="listed">y</span>
                        <span class="listed">k</span>
                        <span class="listed">r</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check it after removing the element.

```
$('.listed').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
    check_empty();
});
function check_empty() {
    console.log($('#word_splatter'))
    if ($('#word_splatter').find('.listed').length) {
        alert('The container contains something.');
    } else {
        alert('The container is empty.');
    }
}
```

[**You can see DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ohwoke1e/)